# UITableView customized for collapse/expand cells in Storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.5

Does anyone know a tutorial showing how to implement an UITableView that collapses and expands cells (grouping them) in Storyboard?
Something like:

Name (expand/collapse)

- John (click to show John's info, new ViewController)
- Sam (idem)
- Paul (idem)

Sports (expand/collapse)

- Basketball
- Baseball
- Football

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in following ways:

Insert new cells while selecting a cell at specified index path:

```
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
    [tableView endUpdates];
```

And then deleting these on next tap:

```
[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:YES];
```

In this way you'll have to update the datasource(i.e your array) and the index path of tap-able cells with no of new additions and removing in table.

Or you can add/remove only cell with a table in it on cell selection.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get. This is adding/removing new cells? I thought about cells with fixed values, collpasing/expanding them (grouping) and linking those which are expanded to another view controller (screen).

Comment: @Adami you are right this is. And that's the how we can manage it.. :)